# Implement stacking to my inventory system in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a game, and now I've just finished the inventory system, which is highly inspired by the one Brackeys made a while back. Right now the player can pick up items, which will go into the inventory's list and be displayed on some UI. After having finished this, I tried to make items stack together, however I was never able to find a working solution. I don't want anything fancy, I just want every item to be able to stack infinitely. If anyone could help me out I'd greatly appreciate it!

Sorry for putting so much code in here, I'm not sure what I should and shouldn't add.

My "Items" script:

```
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New item", menuName = "Inventory/Items")]
public class Item : ScriptableObject
{

    new public string name = "New item";
    public Sprite icon = null;
    public bool itemDefaut = false;

    public virtual void Use()
    {
        Debug.Log("Using " + name);
    }

}
```

My "Inventory" script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{

    #region Singleton

    public static Inventory instance;

    void Awake()
    {

        if (instance != null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("More than one inventory instance found!");
            return;
        }
        
        instance = this;
    }

    #endregion

    public delegate void OnItemChanged();
    public OnItemChanged onItemChangedCallback;

    public List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

    public void Add(Item item)
    {
        items.Add(item);

        if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
        {
            onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
        }
        
    }
    public void Remove(Item item)
    {
        items.Remove(item);

        if (onItemChangedCallback != null)
        {
            onItemChangedCallback.Invoke();
        }
    }

}
```

My "InventorySlot" script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class InventorySlot : MonoBehaviour
{

    Item item;

    public Image icon;

    public void AddItem(Item newItem)
    {
        item = newItem;
        icon.sprite = item.icon;
        icon.enabled = true;
    }
    public void RemoveItem()
    {
        item = null;
        icon.sprite = null;
        icon.enabled = false;
    }



    public void UseItem()
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            item.Use();
        }
    }

}
```

My "InventoryUI" script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class InventoryUI : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform itemsParent;
    public GameObject inventoryUI;

    Inventory inventory;

    InventorySlot[] slots;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        inventory = Inventory.instance;
        inventory.onItemChangedCallback += UpdateUI;

        slots = itemsParent.GetComponentsInChildren<InventorySlot>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Inventory"))
        {
            inventoryUI.SetActive(!inventoryUI.activeSelf);
        }

        if (inventoryUI.activeSelf)
        {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }


    void UpdateUI()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < slots.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i < inventory.items.Count)
            {
                slots[i].AddItem(inventory.items[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                slots[i].RemoveItem();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

My "ItemPickup" script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ItemPickup : Interactable
{

    public Item item;

    public override void Interact()
    {
        base.Interact();

        PickUp();
    }


    void PickUp()
    {

        

        Debug.Log("Picking up " + item.name);
        Inventory.instance.Add(item);
        Destroy(gameObject);

    }

}
```

And my "Interactable" script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Interactable : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float radius = 3f;
    [SerializeField] Player player;
    bool interacted = false;


    void Start()
    {
        interacted = false;
    }


    public virtual void Interact()
    {
        //This method is meant to be overwritten
        Debug.Log("Interacting with " + transform.name);
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (!interacted)
        {
            float distance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, transform.position);
            
            if (distance <= radius)
            {
                Interact();
                interacted = true;
            }
        }

    }

    

    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, radius);
    }


}
```

Finally, here's what my hierarchy looks like for my inventory (just replace "inventaire" by "inventory" and don't mind the item names):

[image: My hierarchy]

Comment: Add a count variable to the items and maintain it as you stack and unstack items.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly it sounds like you basically want a counter for the slot so you can add multiple of the `Item` instance.

You could probably do something like

```
public class InventorySlot : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Have a counter for the amount of items added
    int _amount;
    Item item;

    public Image icon;
    public Text amountText;

    // optionally add an amount parameter
    // if not passed 1 is used but allows to add multiple at once
    public void AddItem(Item newItem, int amount = 1)
    {
        // If there is no item yet
        // then simply add the first one
        if(!item)
        {
            item = newItem;
            icon.sprite = item.icon;
            icon.enabled = true;
            _amount = amount;
        }
        else
        {
            // Otherwise check first if it is the same item
            if(item != newItem)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning($"Type mismatch between current item {item} and added item {newItem}!", this);
                // TODO handle this?
                return;
            }

            // simply increase the amount
            _amount += amount;
        }

        // update text
        amountText.text = _amount.ToString();
    }

    // Again maybe add optional parameter
    // if nothing is passed 1 is used
    // but allows to remove multiple at once
    public void RemoveItem(int amount = 1)
    {
        // check if enough
        if(!item)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("This slot is empty! Can't remove", this);
            // TODO handle this?
            return;
        }

        if(_amount - amount < 0)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning($"Not enough items in this slot to remove {amount}!", this);
        }

        // simply reduce the amount
        _amount -= amount;
        // update the text
        _amountText.text = amount.ToString();

        // Only if you reached 0 -> removed the last item 
        // reset this slot
        if(amount == 0)
        {
            item = null;
            icon.sprite = null;
            icon.enabled = false;
        }
    }



    public void UseItem()
    {
        if (item)
        {
            item.Use();
            // TODO also remove one?
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work, the only thing is that right now items are still added in other slots even if there is already a slot with that item type in it. I'm guessing I have to modify my "Inventory" script to do that, however I'm not sure how to that, as it's in a different script. I'm sure there's an easy way to accomplish this, I just don't know it.